# Trouble with Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When I hide a modal I have to hide it like so:

```
$("#finishBillingModal").css("display", "none");
$(".modal-backdrop").remove();
```

Why?

**EDIT**

I have found the solution like this:

> $(selector).modal({show: true, backdrop: false});

But might be this the correct way ...

Comment: You can also get rid of a modal by simulating a click on the close button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap modals are supposed to be hidden this way:

```
$("#finishBillingModal").modal("hide");
```

as per the [v3 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) *and* the [v2.3.2 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals).

Comment: It does not work ... I have to force calling those two methods: $("#finishBillingModal").css("display", "none");
$(".modal-backdrop").remove();

Comment: Do you create a modal with `$("#finishBillingModal").modal()` ? Can you post a snippet?

Comment: Opening: `$("#finishBillingModal").modal("show");`
Closing: `$("#finishBillingModal").modal("hide");`
Force closing: `$("#finishBillingModal").css("display", "none");
        $(".modal-backdrop").remove();`

Comment: Are there bootstrap or jquery-related errors in js console? Which bootstrap version are you using? Can you re-create an issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: Oh God, re-create this issue is a bit complex ... I will try